# Cannot get mouse click event after lost focus

Tags: c++, winapi

I am working on a exist project and trying to add a extra window to it. I managed to create the window but the original window cannot get mouse click event if I call ShowWindow(m_hwnd, SW_SHOW) to show my extra window. However the original window can get mouse move event.

It looks like that the original window doesn't handle some event properly so that it cannot be activated by mouse click, but I do not know which event triggered the activation.

here's the list of messages processed by original window:

```
WM_CLOSE
WM_MOUSEACTIVATE
WM_ENTERSIZEMOVE
WM_EXITSIZEMOVE
WM_ENTERMENULOOP
WM_EXITMENULOOP
WM_HOTKEYWM_SYSCHAR
WM_CHAR
WM_SYSKEYDOWN
WM_SETCURSOR
WM_MOUSEMOVE
WM_LBUTTONDOWN
WM_LBUTTONUP
WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK
WM_MOVE
WM_SIZE
WM_ACTIVATE
WM_SETFOCUS
WM_KILLFOCUS
WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED
WM_STYLECHANGED
WM_INPUTLANGCHANGE
```

Comment: It does not seem clear to me what your problem is. Do you mean that once you show your child window, the main window cannot be focused on by clicking on it anymore ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide more info to make your question clear. Anyway, mouse messages receive only window that the mouse hovers over it (either client or non-client area), plus the window for which `SetCapture` was called. So your "problem" is probably not due to "incorrect message processing", but because of misunderstanding of input message concept. Also, I think disabled windows don't receive input messages (those for which `EnableWindow(hWnd, FALSE)` was called).